# Error building ionic 2 app - Admob plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, build, admob

I am trying to build my ionic 2 app (sudo ionic cordova build android) but I am getting the following error:

```
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.4, but version 9.0.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4, but version 9.0.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.
:processDebugGoogleServices
FAILED
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.

  > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

I also shared the following message that appeared during the build operation. It does look suspicious to me:

```
google-services plugin could not detect any version for com.google.android.gms or com.google.firebase, default version: 9.0.0 will be used.
please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file.
```

There are all the plugins that my app has:

```
com-sarriaroman-photoviewer 1.1.11 "PhotoViewer"
cordova-admob-sdk 0.13.1 "AdMob SDK"
cordova-plugin-admob-free 0.13.0 "Cordova AdMob Plugin"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-fcm 2.1.2 "FCMPlugin"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.16 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
cordova-promise-polyfill 0.0.2 "cordova-promise-polyfill"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

I have to say that this error message has appeared after adding "Cordova AdMob Plugin" plugin.

Can anyone help me with this issue? I am stuck and I have no idea how to solve the issue.

Let me know if you need further information.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Updating android sdk might be help you. I got same error for google analytics plugin so after updating sdk i got it working

Comment: I've checked this and all of them are installed even Android 8.0.0 SDK Platform. Could it be a issue with FCM plugin?

Comment: Solved! I installed "cordova-plugin-admobpro-firebase" instead of "cordova-plugin-admob-free" and everything is working fine